# Motorola TC55 refuses to show up in adb

Tags: android, adb

I can not get the Motorola TC55 to show up in the adb (using Mac OSX), and their support lines are less than unhelpful.

I have tried adding the vendors to the .ini file, I have tried toggling on/off the usb debugging, and the development options.

I have tried killing and restarting adb.
I have tried restarting laptop and TC55.
I have tried 3 cables.

I have tried it when using the device storage option and without.

It says `USB connected`, `USB debugging connected`, and `connected as installer` in the notifications menu.

I tried installing Motorola Device Manager for Mac, which seems to do nothing.

I am at a dead end. Besides emailing myself test builds, what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried on other OSs? Have you tried to start adb with root?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it's for mac then you can open terminal and type in following.

`echo 0x05e0 >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini`

0x05e0 is the Vendor ID for the TC55.

Once done, restart your adb.

`cd your_path_to_adb
./adb kill-server
./adb devices`

You should see your device in the list.

`* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
132665216D0010  device`

If not, try unplug the device and plug-in and do *./adb devices* again. It just worked for me few minutes ago ;)

!!! dont forget to do all this again each time you update your ADB..

Comment: Thankyou, this slaughtered me for a long time xD I finally had motorola get back to me with what you just said, but I forgot to post the answer, But since you beat me too it, you can have it xD :)

Comment: No mention ;) im currently working with this device as well. Next will be the Data Wedge :)

Comment: Cool.. now i know who to contact if i have some issue with it ;)

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was missing

Comment: What a life saver!  Saved my bacon at least.

Comment: Saved my bacon.  Now how do I install apps on this thing (like Chrome) without Google Play?!

Comment: if you already have the apk file then just transfer the apk file via usb or sdcard and install it (first switch on Unknown sources in the Settings-> Security). If you dont have  the apk file, then get an android device which has google play, download an app call Apk Extractor and choose chrome or any other apps you like then extract the apk and then transfer to TC55 then install it..  Good luck.. oh ya root access not needed..

Comment: Saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I am running Windows 10. It worked under Windows 7, but since I upgraded, it stopped working.

Tried a lot of the above, all not working for me. Ended up installing a (apparently) new version of the usb driver for the TC55 from https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=99052&productDetailGUID=17bba9494c7a0410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=2202caf8fb16e310VgnVCM1000000389bd0aRCRD

That worked fine, adb recognizes my TC55 again!

Answer (score 2):

For windows 7, I had to install the motorola android usb driver from https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-1880. There's instructions for windows and linux but not mac.

Your best route is probably going to be going to https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN and contacting support.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution for Mac users:

### Find the vender Id of android devices

**$system_profiler SPUSBDataType**
Android:
Product ID: 0x3f0c
Vendor ID: 0x1d91   // **here it is**
Version:  2.33
Serial Number: MotorolaXT788
Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
Manufacturer: Android
Location ID: 0x14100000 / 14
Current Available (mA): 500
Current Required (mA): 500

**$echo 0x1d91 >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini**
**$adb kill-server**
**$adb devices**

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone out there is as dumb as I am, there are two ports available on the device; the docking port on the bottom, and the USB port along the side. The docking port **cannot** be used for USB debugging.

On Windows 10, the device *should* automatically install once connected. Then you just need to enable USB Debugging within the Developer Options. (Jelly Bean 4.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac with OS X Yosemite the Motorola TC55 shows like the following:

```
 Android:

              Product ID: 0x2100
              Vendor ID: 0x05e0  (Symbol Technologies)
              Version: 2.28
              Serial Number: 14023521650310
              Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
              Manufacturer: Android
              Location ID: 0xfd311000 / 8
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Current Required (mA): 500
              Extra Operating Current (mA): 400
```

In my case: 
I navigated to my home directory "/myuserdir/.android"
Used the command "echo 0x05e0 >> adb_usb.ini".
It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could try, because in my case I tried all this and it didn't work.  I reset the TC55 by pressing on the power button and after it finish restarting, it worked.